# AWKの one-linerでファイル比較し、一致しないレコードを抽出したいですが、うまく行かないことがあります。

Tags: awk

■実行コマンド
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{minus[$1]++; next;} !minus[$1]' file2 file1

■file2の内容
c
d
e

■file1の内容
a,あ,い,う,え,お
b,あ,い,う,え,お
c,あ,い,う,え,お
d,あ,い,う,え,お
e,あ,い,う,え,お
f,あ,い,う,え,お
g,あ,い,う,え,お
h,あ,い,う,え,お

■期待結果
a,あ,い,う,え,お
b,あ,い,う,え,お
f,あ,い,う,え,お
g,あ,い,う,え,お
h,あ,い,う,え,お

■実際結果
a,あ,い,う,え,お
b,あ,い,う,え,お
c,あ,い,う,え,お
d,あ,い,う,え,お
e,あ,い,う,え,お
f,あ,い,う,え,お
g,あ,い,う,え,お
h,あ,い,う,え,お

いろいろを調べてみましたが、原因不明のままです。
ご教示お願い致します。

Comment: 手元のUbuntu22.04.1 LTSでUTF-8のファイルを使って試したところ、期待結果が表示されました。

Comment: file2 ですが、行末にスペースやタブが入っていないでしょうか？

Comment: @payaneco ご確認ありがとうございます！
Ubuntu22.04.1 LTSで正常に動作していますね。こちらの環境は、Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTSです。

この結果だと、環境依存ですね。これを解決する方法がご存知でしょうか？
一応one command linerをやめて、awk

Comment: @payaneco 
一応one command linerをやめて、awkプログラミングで処理したら問題ないですが。

Comment: @metropolis  ご確認ありがとうございます！
行末にCRLFコードしかないですね。LFでも試してみましたが同じ結果ですね。

Comment: `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`と申し上げましたが、`Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`にアップデート済みでした。失礼いたしました。

Comment: `grep -v -f file2 file1` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: インデックスとして値を求めて条件判断するのではなく，配列のインデックスに含まれるか否かで判断する方法では如何でしょうか。 `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{minus[$1]=1; next} !($1 in minus)' file2 file1`

Answer (score 0):

`Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`の`mawk 1.3.4 20200120`、および下記の手順で`gawk-5.2.0`をユーザフォルダに落として動作確認したところ期待通りの結果となりました。

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/gawk-5.2.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf gawk-5.2.0.tar.gz 
cd gawk-5.2.0/
./configure 
make
./gawk -F, 'NR==FNR{minus[$1]++; next;} !minus[$1]' file2 file1
```

`awk`のバージョン見直しと、`gawk`でも再現するかをご確認ください。